# swfupload cancelling upload

Tags: jquery, flash, swfupload, ajax-upload

I have a form which is using swfupload with the jquery plugin.

I have some required fields which should be filled before I allow upload.

So I add a handler to `file_dialog_complete_handler`

Somethings like,

```
  file_dialog_complete_handler = function(dom_el){
   alert(10);
   dom_el.cancelUpload();
   return false;
  }
```

This doesnt work as I dont know where is the `cancelUpload` defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, I think I would approach this a different way.  If you require other form fields to be filled-in/validated before the user can upload files, then start the SWFUload with the parameter `button_disabled : true`.  This will make it impossible to press the button to select files and queue-up/upload files.

Then, you can set a handler on your form inputs (onchange, onkeyup, etc.) that checks the data in your form and if it checks out, then use the method: `[your SWFU object].setButtonDisabled(false)` which will enable the button, and your user can now upload files.

This is the method I use to accomplish what you're after.

cancelUpload is another method on the SWFUpload object and is documented here: http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#cancelUpload

Since you've tagged this as jQuery, you might be interested in the jQuery.swfupload plugin that makes like very easy for you.  Check it out here: http://github.com/ifunk/swfupload-jquery-plugin

I hope this helps.